# Setting a configuration using python flask and and hanling import error

Tags: python, module, flask

This is my first time using python flask and am getting a runtime errors when setting a config.py file.Most of the tutorials are using sqlite while I use mysql. How do I get to set a config.py file using MySQL as my database when making a Restful.
Also ,I have a lot of import errors like no module named sqlalchemy or n module named restful.Tried pip installing them again but have the same error.Does anyone know how to solve this .Thank you

Comment: Would you please post the code that you have so far?

Comment: And all the error message might also be helpful.

Comment: This is my config.py code